# Android: MapView Projection inaccurate

Tags: android, android-mapview, point, projection

Because of some calculations I have to transform a GeoPoint to screen coordinates, do something with them and then transform them back to a GeoPoint.

Sadly after those transformations the new GeoPoint is allways 0-2 mm away (on the screen) from the point I want to have.

Surprisingly following lines of code allready change the GeoPoint a bit.

```
Projection projection = map.getProjection(); 
Log.d("bevore", geoPoint.getLatitudeE6() +" "+geoPoint.getLongitudeE6());
Point pt = new Point();

projection.toPixels(geoPoint, pt);

geoPoint = projection.fromPixels(pt.x, pt.y);
Log.d("after", geoPoint.getLatitudeE6() +" | "+geoPoint.getLongitudeE6());
```

And the output is:

```
 D/bevore(31252): 53106803 | 8852244
 D/after(31252): 53106802 | 8852240
```

Is there a way to improove this inaccuracy.

Comment: Could this be a problem of resolution? (i.e. one pixel covering many geopoints).  To test, take the 'after' geopoint, and run it through the same process.  If it is a resolution problem, it should come out unchanged.  If it is an error in the projection, then it should come out shifted by the same margin.

Comment: You are right. It comes out unchanged. Does this mean, that there is no way to improve it?

Comment: You should be able to improve the resolution of the map (probably by zooming it in).  You just need to expand it sufficiently that each lat/long geopoint can be individually resolved to a different pixel.

Comment: @anonymous I believe that you are facing two different issues. The one that you demostrate with the example code, and that logical Chimp explained, which should point always to the same screen point (no 0-2mm difference) unless, you zoom or change the map position between conversions. If you are facing misplacing issues (0-2mm) converting to scrren point and back to geolocation without changing the map position or zoom, then you have some other issue.

Comment: Your "difference" shown above is 1 microdegree in latitude and 4 microdegrees in longitude. That is at most ~41 centimeters (less towards the poles), well below the tightest zoom level of any map you will use with `MapView`.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the difference once between `GeoPoint` before and after conversion and add it to the results of `fromPixels` everytime you need to.

```
Projection projection = map.getProjection();
projection.toPixels(geoPointBefore, pt);
geoPointAfter = projection.fromPixels(pt.x, pt.y);

int diffLatitude  = geoPointBefore.getLatitudeE6()  - geoPointAfter.getLatitudeE6();
int diffLongitude = geoPointBefore.getLongitudeE6() - geoPointAfter.getLongitudeE6();
...
...
...
// Add the difference to GeoPoint objects after conversion `fromPixels`
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but you could try to multiple by 10 or 100 before you convert the geopoint in pixels, in this way you will have a less error when you round to E6.
I hope it will help you.